# Service Worker Cache memory

Tags: javascript

In progressive Web App using the service worker the request given is stored in the cache memory. If the content updated in the server whether the same content in the cache memory will updated, how it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Jake Archibald's [article](https://jakearchibald.com/2016/caching-best-practices/) on caching strategies and service workers. I think this is exactly what you are looking for.

Also note that [sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache), a tool for generating service workers, will hash your cached content automatically and likely solve some caching issues for you.